# Ruby watir nokogiri browser integration

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, watir

So I've created a parser using ruby and gems such as watir and nokigiri. I've created it on a Debian box. It works amazing, but I don't know what to do next. I want it to work within a browser and on other platforms (e.g Windows, OSX, etc.) without a terminal window open. I'm sure there is a simple solution, but I would also like input from the community.

Comment: OR I would like a couple of buttons on Firefox/ice weasel that perform a function call in the irb terminal.

Comment: There isn't a simple solution if you don't understand web-services or CGIs or how something like Sinatra or Rails works. You will need several components, and explaining them is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I hope this question is a joke because I can't imagine being trapped in a mind that would ask it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using gems. 'headless' and 'watir-webdriver' my ruby script runs completely headless in the terminal. [headless|Watir WebDriver](http://watirwebdriver.com/headless/)

Answer (score 0):

> an iframe that is running watir

i dont think thats possible. it would run on the server, interacting with a real browser imitating a real users actions.

you can make it headless, so that it doesnt open up a browser window. i use [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) and [poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist) but you could also checkout [watirmelon](http://watirmelon.com/tag/headless/)

Comment: I'm using watir to pass the java embedded webpage to nokogiri.

Comment: The reason why I want to have both access to function calls and the power of a full web browser is so i can see the web page before i parse the content.